# Как спарсить правильно json, в котором есть массив объектов?

Tags: java, json

У меня задача спарсить json в котором массив объектов, затем преобразовать в классы и распечатать.
Что тут я делаю не так?

код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setPrettyPrinting()
            .create();

    String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpClient = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        httpClient.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpClient.setRequestProperty("User", "Google Ghrome");
        int responseCode = httpClient.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("URL сайта: " + url);
        System.out.println("код ответа: " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpClient.getInputStream()));
        

        User[]  users = gson.fromJson(in, User[].class);
        System.out.println(users);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В классе `User` нужно переопределить метод `toString()`:

   ```
    class User{

        public int userId;
        public int id;
        public String title;
        public String body;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User{" +
                    "userId=" + userId +
                    ", id=" + id +
                    ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                    ", body='" + body + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
   ```
2. Использовать метод `Arrays.toString()` для печати массива:

   ```
    User[] users = gson.fromJson(in, User[].class);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(users));
   ```

Comment: спасибо, оказывается проблема была совсем мелкой))